# Does exercising lower your lifespan?

Tags: exercise, muscle, life-expectancy, metabolism, physiology

- I read that the consumption rate (Cal) of stronger muscles while resting is higher than that of less dense muscle tissue.
- Kleiber's Law and Rate of Living Theory states that organisms have circa the same heartbeats per lifetime (~one billion [which still has some exceptions])
- Also assume that the extra exercise is counteracted (by augmented caloric input or something) so that the benefits of exercise is disregarded.

If you don't live shorter because of it, then why?

Comment: Your question is actually: is lifespan capped by the number of heartbeats?

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to know about exercising in particular, if that changes anything.

Comment: Then the three points in your question are meaningless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Persons who do regular physical exercise have a lower heart rate while they are resting (or not exercising):

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22081187

Hence, their hearts will be beating same number of beats over a longer period of time.

In addition, a number of trials have shown that regular physical exercise is associated with significant health benefits and lower incidence of serious health problems, e.g.:

http://www.thelancet.com/journals/lancet/article/PIIS0140-6736(04)17018-9/abstract

Comment: thank you! I'm just wondering; how did you find that first source?

Comment: Pubmed is a regular source to search for medical journal articles. I just picked the first article that showed this aspect. There are many other references also on this topic. The second reference is, of course, one of the top cited articles from a very high ranking journal.